How landing pad offset and action index can both be 0?
So, I am doing my own personality function (because I can).
In this function, I am parsing a call site table. Each record has four fields - callsite offset, callsite length, landing pad offset and action idx.
My algorithm in relation to this table is pretty much as follows:

If the address of instruction that threw is less then any callsite address - terminate;

If landing pad offset is zero - continue unwinding;

If action idx is zero:
a. if still looking - continue unwinding;
b. if doing clean-up - transfer control to landing pad.


Every record is parsed sequentially from lowest to highest.
For a simple C++ code like this:
  void raise() {
     printf("Beggining of raise\n");
     struct DestroyMe {
         volatile int payload;
          DestroyMe() {
              printf("DESTROY ME raise\n");
              payload = 1;
          };
         ~DestroyMe() {
             printf("I AM DESTOYED raise\n");
             payload = 0;
         };
     };
     DestroyMe dm{};
     printf("Before throw\n");
     throw Exception();
 }

clang gives the following call site table:

  .Lcst_begin0:
      .uleb128 .Lfunc_begin0-.Lfunc_begin0    # >> Call Site 1 <<
      .uleb128 .Ltmp0-.Lfunc_begin0           #   Call between .Lfunc_begin0 and .Ltmp0
      .byte   0                               #     has no landing pad
      .byte   0                               #   On action: cleanup
      .uleb128 .Ltmp0-.Lfunc_begin0           # >> Call Site 2 <<
      .uleb128 .Ltmp1-.Ltmp0                  #   Call between .Ltmp0 and .Ltmp1
      .uleb128 .Ltmp4-.Lfunc_begin0           #     jumps to .Ltmp4
      .byte   0                               #   On action: cleanup
      .uleb128 .Ltmp1-.Lfunc_begin0           # >> Call Site 3 <<
      .uleb128 .Ltmp2-.Ltmp1                  #   Call between .Ltmp1 and .Ltmp2
      .byte   0                               #     has no landing pad
      .byte   0                               #   On action: cleanup
      .uleb128 .Ltmp2-.Lfunc_begin0           # >> Call Site 4 <<
      .uleb128 .Ltmp3-.Ltmp2                  #   Call between .Ltmp2 and .Ltmp3
      .uleb128 .Ltmp4-.Lfunc_begin0           #     jumps to .Ltmp4
      .byte   0                               #   On action: cleanup
      .uleb128 .Ltmp3-.Lfunc_begin0           # >> Call Site 5 <<
      .uleb128 .Lfunc_end0-.Ltmp3             #   Call between .Ltmp3 and .Lfunc_end0
      .byte   0                               #     has no landing pad
      .byte   0                               #   On action: cleanup

My questions are:

How come landing pad and action idx are both 0 when there are destructors to call?

Even if this is normal, then what should be checked first?

Even if this is normal (#2), how can I transfer control to cleanup when landing pad is 0? It will just go to the start of the function.


I checked with this implementation, and my logic seem to align with it. Handlers are working fine and control is passed to the expected catch blocks. This is just a problem with clean-ups that I cannot solve for weeks.
I also used mostly these links (among others) as a reference, but none of them answer my questions:
Itanium spec;
Another Itanium spec;
Awesome blog post.

I don't really understand the question but still think volatile looks wrong. Why is payload volatile? Is there hardware or something being able to change the value of payload without the the compiler knowing about it?

@TedLyngmo the stores are optimized out otherwise.

Yeah, I added volatile as the last step "just to make sure", because at the moment I ran out of ideas.
